# (426): Upgrade Required error for newsapi.org

Tags: http-headers, powerbi

I'm a noob at data analytics, I am using PowerBi Desktop 2019. I am trying to get data via API call from newsapi.org

I have researched the HTTP error (426) but I don't know what it means or what to do to fix it:

> "The server refuses to perform the request using the current protocol
>   but might be willing to do so after the client upgrades to a different
>   protocol.
>
> The server MUST send an Upgrade header field in a 426 response to
>   indicate the required protocol(s)"

Here is the error I get in PowerBi when I make the API call (I scrambled my API key in the example below)

> Details: Web.Contents failed to get contents from
>   'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=poppins&from=2019-05-05&to=2020-05-05&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=1111111111111111111'
>   (426): Upgrade Required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I think ...

When I call for just one month's wort of data, it works fine.

I am assuming "Upgrade required" in this instance means I can't use the current method to call for more data and have to get a different (paid) authorisation from newsapi.org